# Plot specific element values in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a list as below:

```
freq = [29342, 28360, 26029, 21418, 20771, 18372, 18239, 18070, 17261, 17102]
```

I want to show the values of n-th and m-th element of the x-axis and draw a vertical line

```
plt.plot(freq[0:1000])
```

[image]

For example in the graph above, the 100th elements on the x-axis - how can I show the values on the line?

[image]

I tried to knee but it shows only one elbow. I suggest it is the 50th element? But what is exactly `x,y`??

```
from kneed import KneeLocator
kn = KneeLocator(list(range(0, 1000)), freq[0:1000], curve='convex', direction='decreasing')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
kn.plot_knee()
#plt.axvline(x=50, color='black', linewidth=2, alpha=.7) 
plt.annotate(freq[50], xy=(50, freq[50]), size=10)
```

[image]

Comment: That '100' is fixed? If you want to show a vertical line you can use
plt.axvline(x=100, color='black', linewidth=2, alpha=.7)
plt.annotate(freq[100], xy=(100, freq[100]), size=8)

Comment: @solopiu Or define your own annotation function that takes ax, a list of x-indexes, and freq as parameters and annotates your curve as you just have shown. Surprisingly, I did not find easily a duplicate, so go ahead - I will upvote it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works, Actually I want to apply zipf distribution of my corpus and find elbow points values. I draw first elbow point with kneelocator but ı did not found the value of elbow.

Comment: Sliiiightly different question.

Comment: kn.plot_knee() shows an elbow, but what is the value of it? I think if I merge two plot, I can guess the values x and y on the elbow exactly.

Comment: 50. elements value is 1225. I don't know whether is the elbow the 50th element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might think that everybody knows this library `kneed`. Well, I don't know about others but I have never seen that one before (it does not even have a tag here on SO).
But [their documentation](https://kneed.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html) is excellent (`qhull` take note!). So, you could do something like this:

```
#fake data generation
import numpy as np
x=np.linspace(1, 10, 100)
freq=x**(-1.9) 

#here happens the actual plotting
from kneed import KneeLocator
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

kn = KneeLocator(x, freq, curve='convex', direction='decreasing')
xk = kn.knee
yk = kn.knee_y

kn.plot_knee()

plt.annotate(f'Found knee at x={xk:.2f}, y={yk:.2f}', xy=(xk*1.1, yk*1.1) )

plt.show()
```

Sample output:

[image]